# UIPrintInteractionController in iPad is giving me two warnings

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit

I am using a code to get Airprint in my app to print the current view as an image.
the Airprint dialog pops up but in the log screen it shows me two warnings :

1) **WARNING: Calling -[UIPrintInteractionController presentAnimated:completionHandler:] on iPad
failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.**

2)**[UIPopoverController_commonPresentPopoverFromRect:
inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: the rect passed in to this method must have non-zero width and height. This will be an exception in a future release.**

I have already searched in the net but found that all solutions provided for regular rect Button

what I am using here is a segmented control, and I don't know how to use this control in this situation

here is the segment control code :

```
- (IBAction)legalSegment:(id)sender {


switch (((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
    case 0:
    {
        [self printItem];
        break;
    }
}
```

and this is the printItem method :

```
-(void)printItem {
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIPrintInteractionController* pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)];
if (pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:imageData])
{
    pic.delegate = self;
    UIPrintInfo* printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputPhoto;
    printInfo.jobName = @"PrintingImage";
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    pic.printInfo = printInfo;
    pic.showsPageRange = YES;
    pic.printingItem = imageData;

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) {
            NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
        }
    };

    [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
}
```

any help will be great.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On iPad, you should use the popover API provided by the controller. It is mentioned in the documentation.

> `presentAnimated:completionHandler:`
>
> **Presents the iPhone printing user interface** in a sheet that can be
>   animated to slide up from the bottom of the screen.
>
> `presentFromBarButtonItem:animated:completionHandler:`
>
> **Presents the iPad printing user interface** in a popover view that can
>   be animated from a bar-button item.
>
> `presentFromRect:inView:animated:completionHandler:`
>
> **Presents the iPad printing user interface** in a popover view that can
>   be animated from any area in a view.

You should use the correct method on the corresponding device type.

```
if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    [pic presentFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
else {
    [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

You should use appropriate parameters for the popover presentation.

Comment: well thanks my friend,, that solved half of the problem but still giving me **failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.** in log screen!! any ideas?

Comment: @AbdulmalikMorghem I am not sure about that. Is the print successful or does it fail?

Comment: I am using simulator and no attached printer to my Mac machine..so Airprint dialog will not enable print button.. :/

Comment: I guess the problem that I used `UIImagePNGRepresentation` not pdf. Don't you agree?