# WARNING: Calling -[UIPrinterPickerController presentAnimated:completionHandler:] on iPad

Tags: swift4

I am using UIPrinterPickerController for selecting any one printer in printer list but UIPickerController doesn't open when I am running code to IPAD simulator but this same code I will run to IPHONE simulator is correct and show my all simulator printer and I can select any printer and get printer name as well as there url.

```
    let pickerController = UIPrinterPickerController(initiallySelectedPrinter: nil)
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
       pickerController.present(animated: true) {(controller,completed,error) in
                if completed == true {
                    let ipadprintername = controller.selectedPrinter!.displayName
                }
            }
}else{
 pickerController.present(animated: true){(controller, completed,error)in
                  if completed == true {
                    let iphoneprintername = controller.selectedPrinter!.displayName
                } 
            }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIPrintInteractionController in iPad is giving me two warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20916628/uiprintinteractioncontroller-in-ipad-is-giving-me-two-warnings)

Comment: Let me explain you, I am using  UIPrinterPickerController for select printer and then another button to print document direct without open print preview window(UIPrintInteractionController) , in both device iPhone and iPad but in iPhone run successfully this code but iPad doesn't show UIPrinterPickerController.

Answer (score 4):

```
 if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    let pickerController = UIPrinterPickerController(initiallySelectedPrinter: nil)
    pickerController.present(from: CGRect(x: 400, y: 200, width: 0, height: 0), in: view, animated: true){( controller,completed,error)  in
    if completed == true {
       let printername = controller.selectedPrinter!.displayName
     }
  }
 }else{
   let pickerController = UIPrinterPickerController(initiallySelectedPrinter: nil)
   pickerController.present(animated: true) { (controller, completed, error) in
   if completed == true {
      let printername = controller.selectedPrinter!.displayName
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: thank you sir for this suggestion, next time I will remember this.